# Await Not Working With Firebase Firestore Calls Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await

For some reason this works

```
const docRef = doc(db, "users", "1");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
const currentWeek = docSnap.get('currentWeek')
const onLoadPage = docSnap.get('currentPage')
```

But this doesn't

```
function getCurrentPage() {
const docRef = doc(db, "users", "1");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
const currentWeek = docSnap.get('currentWeek')
};
```

It hangs up on the 'await' and the console says

> Unexpected reserved word (Points to await)

Why does it work the first time but not the second?
This happens all the time and I dont understand it

It seems to me that this is happening because await is being used consecutively.
Await seems to work when used localy within things but if its used twice in a open area it doesn't seem to like it

Comment: `async function getCurrentPage() {
const docRef = doc(db, "users", "1");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
const currentWeek = docSnap.get('currentWeek')
};`

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that I need to use it within a async function